# Personnalized listview in Android like Facebook Messenger or Viber

Tags: android

I am beginning in Android developpment and am developping an app in wich i have a listview i want to be scrolling as in apps like Viber where we have the option to scroll to old messages with a fixed bar above like in in this picture http://taiviber.edu.vn/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/tai-viber1.jpg.

Suggestions appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something similar to this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/top_control_bar">

        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/sort_by"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottom_control_bar"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Add Item" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:choiceMode="multipleChoice"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_control_bar"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar"></ListView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/empty"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/top_control_bar"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_control_bar" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Using the layout above you are able to achieve what you need with a `Spinner` in the header and a `Button` in the footer.

Source: http://blog.maxaller.name/2010/05/attaching-a-sticky-headerfooter-to-an-android-listview/

To achieve a chat layout similar to Viber please see the following links:

http://warting.se/2012/06/04/chat-bubbles-in-android/

http://warting.github.io/AndroidChatBubbles/

Comment: Thanks very much @Leigh for your answer, its very useful. I want more  closer suggestions to the goal - if possible- any way. thank you.

Comment: @user3232174 you need to be clearer what it is you're looking for. This layout should achieve what you need, is there something else you're stuck with?

Comment: Actually @Leigh i want to have at least an idea on how the designers of Viber for Android  make the listview of chat. hope this is clear, thnx

Comment: @user3232174 Please see the links in my answer, these should help you out.

Comment: Thank you very much @Leigh will. Gonna chick it

Comment: @user3232174 No problem, just remember if this answer helped you please consider up-voting. If it solved your question please mark as answer using the tick above.